# http put request to upload a file flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, http, curl

How to write this in dart with the http package the -F takes the file not the file path.

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.groupdocs.cloud/v1.0/parser/storage/file/hello.pdf" 
-H "accept: application/json" 
-H "authorization: Bearer [Access_Token]" 
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-H "x-aspose-client: Containerize.Swagger" 
-F "file"="@C:/Temp/wavenet.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer [Access_Token]'
};
var request = http.MultipartRequest('PUT', Uri.parse('https://api.groupdocs.cloud/v1.0/parser/storage/file'));
request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', '/Users/bholendraofficial/Desktop/BHOLENDRA SINGH RESUME.pdf'));
request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```